# Fedora desktop connection with iPhone

Tags: unix, fedora

I have connected iPhone with Fedora Desktop using VirtualBox. I can find out in "Places" menu but I am trying to find out its device path. I have to add this path in a configuration file like "/dev/?????" etc.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

When the device appears in Places, it's usually mounted.  You can see a list of all mounted devices using the mount command.

For instance:

```
% mount
[...]
/dev/sdc1 on /media/my-phone type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

Notice it says `/dev/sdc1 on /media/my-phone`?  On the right, you'll see the the name that appears in the Places menu, while on the left, the block device in `/dev` is listed.

If it doesn't appear in that list, try selecting it from the Places menu to force it to be mounted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `udevadm monitor` , and then connect the phone and you should see on the screen the results, which include a path. But it isn't sure a `/dev/` path, since for that you have to have some rule on your `udev` system.

Comment: Thanks Hanan. I am getting output some like following
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0b.0/usb1/1-1